# Cloning AJAX TabPanels

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have come across an interesting problem when trying to clone a template panel in my ajax tabcontainer control.

The idea is that i have a custom control on the first tab that lists some things, and to add a new thing you click the new button on the custom control, which raises an event in the control / page that contains the tabcontainer. That control / page then goes about cloning the hidden tabpanel and adding the clone to the tabcontainer.

with this markup I get what I need from both the first tab (containing the list) and any subsequent tabs (templated by the hidden tabpanel ready for cloning) ...

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server">
    <asp:TabPanel ID="ui_pnl1" HeaderText="My Panel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <cc1:myListOfThings ID="list" runat="server" OnMyEvent="CreateTabFromTemplate" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>
    <asp:TabPanel ID="TemplatePanel" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <span>Hello World</span><asp:LinkButton ID="ui_btnRemove" runat="server" Text="x" />
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ContentTemplate>
            Some content for my panel
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>
</asp:TabContainer>
```

Ok now lets assume that on the first panel in my custom control i have a button that raises the "MyEvent" event which in turn calls the method "CreateTabFromTemplate".

Now what I want to do is copy the hidden panel "TemplatePanel" and add it to the tab container.

In my code behind, the method code for adding the new tab panel to my tab container works something like this ...

```
protected void CreateTabFromTemplate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // create a new tab panel
    TabPanel newPanel = new TabPanel();
    // instantiate the hidden content template from the hidden note panel in the new panel
    ui_tpNoteCreator.ContentTemplate.InstantiateIn(newPanel);
    // add the panel to the available tabs and select it
    TabContainer1.Tabs.Add(newPanel);
    TabContainer1.ActiveTab = newPanel;
}
```

All looking good so far ... but i missed something ... I haven't templated the new tabpanels header ... it seems that all I can do is set the text.

Following this example : http://forums.asp.net/t/1108611.aspx/1 I can do what i'm trying to do but I don't want to write a class that defines my header template I want to instantiate an instance of my markup version and pass that instance to my new panel.

I'm not convinced this can be done ... is this a bug with the control or did i miss something ?!?!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out i was going about it the wrong way ...

Essentially theres a difference between assigning templates and the databinding process, it's still not perfect because of the data im trying to pass in to my tab templates but here's the basic principal ...

Markup :

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server">
    <asp:TabPanel ID="ui_pnl1" HeaderText="My Panel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <cc1:myListOfThings ID="list" runat="server" OnMyEvent="CreateTabFromTemplate" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>
    <asp:TabPanel ID="TemplatePanel" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <span>Hello World</span><asp:LinkButton ID="ui_btnRemove" runat="server" Text="x" />
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ContentTemplate>
            Some content for my panel
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>
</asp:TabContainer>
```

Code behind :

```
protected void CreateTabFromTemplate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // create a new tab panel
    TabPanel newPanel = new TabPanel();
newPanel.HeaderTemplate = TemplatePanel.HeaderTemplate;
newPanel.ContentTemplate = TemplatePanel.ContentTemplate;
    // add the panel to the available tabs and select it
    TabContainer1.Tabs.Add(newPanel);
    TabContainer1.ActiveTab = newPanel;
}

protected void TabContainer_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach(TabPanel panel in TabContainer.Tabs)
   {
      //identify if this is the correct tab
      if(correctTab)
      {
          // this will find a control anywhere on the panel (eg in both header and content templates)
          Label label = panel.FindControl("ControlID") as Label;
          label.Text = "Some Business Object Value";
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the following which works as far as I can tell.

Markup:

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
        <asp:TabPanel ID="ui_pnl1" HeaderText="My Panel" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnAddPanel" runat="server" Text="Add Panel" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>
        <asp:TabPanel ID="TemplatePanel" runat="server" Visible ="false">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <span>Hello World</span><asp:LinkButton ID="ui_btnRemove" runat="server" Text="X" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <p>Test Content</p>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>
    </asp:TabContainer>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.btnAddPanel.Click += new EventHandler(btnAddPanel_Click);
    }

    void btnAddPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPanel newPanel = new TabPanel();

        newPanel.HeaderTemplate = TemplatePanel.HeaderTemplate;
        TemplatePanel.ContentTemplate.InstantiateIn(newPanel);

        TabContainer1.Tabs.Add(newPanel);
        TabContainer1.ActiveTab = newPanel;        
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what i was doing ... try combining your code with mine you will see that the content of the tab contains both templates which is wrong ... the content should only contain the contenttemplate code and the header template should define the actual tab itself.